# Se você entrar em uma pergunta e der F5, o , se torna . na quantidade de pontos

Tags: bug

Ao entrar na pergunta

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrxxm.jpg

Depois de dar F5 na pergunta

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Op6.jpg

Comment: Pra mim aparece sempre ponto. Será que não é algo em cache na sua máquina?

Comment: Aqui também tudo normal. Pode ser alguma extensão do Chrome também. Já tentou em outros navegadores?

Comment: Quando a pontuação é atualizada por JS o separador vira vírgula.

Comment: @LINQ já notaram isso antes, agora entendi

Comment: @bfavaretto Deixe uma aba qualquer aberta no SOpt, receba um voto positivo em uma pergunta ou resposta e volte para a aba. Isso reproduz o problema.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Nesse caso, deve ser o JS trocando de volta pra vírgula. Capaz que falte internacionalizar esse js.